# DateTime Format(s) for TimeZone(s) c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, datetime-format

Is there any Date and Time Format List for specific Timezone(s)..?

If so, what is the elegant way to use it in my c# project?

Comment: where is the Jon Skeet Noda bot trawler ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific Date and Time Format list as you require. Instead you have a TimeZone class in c#.

You can go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) link to understand how to use the timezone class.